# Webpage design changes when zooming and/or running on another system

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have developed a webpage in asp.net mvc, when I zoom in or out page, it get scattered. This also happen when I run web on another pc with different resolution of screen size. I have gon through different forums but not enough guidance is available.

Regards

Code for _layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Fleets Go Green DataServer</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <header>                       
        <div class="content-wrapper">
           <div class="div_line">  
             <div class="div_grey"></div>
             <div class="div_blue"></div>
           </div> 

           <div class="empty"></div>
           <div class="div_logo"> 
               <div class="div_left_logo">
                   <img src="~/Images/fgg_logo.gif" > 
               </div>    
               <div class="div_right_logo">
                   <img src="~/Images/fgg_head.gif" > 
               </div>          
            </div> 
             <div class="empty"></div>
             <div class="div_line">  
                 <div class="div_grey"></div>
                 <div class="div_blue"> 
                     <section id="login">
                       @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                     </section>
                 </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="empty"></div>
            <!--
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("Fleets Go Green Get Your Measurement", "Index", "Home")</p>                                        
            </div> 

            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
                <nav>

                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Fahrzeuge", "Index", "Fahrzeuge")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Impressum", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Kontakt", "Contact", "Home")</li>                           
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>-->
        </div>
    </header>
       <!-- Body Layot-->
    <layoutform>
        <div class="div_content">  
             <div class="div_navi">
                 <div class="navi_empty">&nbsp;</div>
                 <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Fahrzeuge", "Index", "Fahrzeuge")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Impressum", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Kontakt", "Contact", "Home")</li>                           
                    </ul>
                  <div class="div_bottom_logo">
                   <img src="~/Images/995_bmu_logo_vmxk9d.png" > 
                </div> 
             </div>
             <div class="div_text"> 
                  @RenderSection("featured", required: false) 
             <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
                  </div>
        </div> 

         <div class="empty"></div>

    </layoutform>

      <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
           <div class="div_line">  
             <div class="div_grey"></div>
             <div class="div_blue">&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Niedersächsisches Forschungszentrum Fahrzeugtechnik (NFF) | IFAM Bremen | 
             </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="empty"></div>

       <!-- <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - imc Meßsysteme GmbH Berlin +49 (0)30 467090-0 - Frankfurt +49 (0)6172 59672-0 - Schweiz +41 (0)52 7221455 - Österreich +49 (0)6172-59672-0</p>
            </div>-->
        </div>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

CSS for the page is below

```
html {
background-color: #e2e2e2;
//background-color: #fff;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-top: solid 10px #333;
color: #333;
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

a {
color: #333;
outline: none;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:link, a:visited,
a:active, a:hover {
    color: #333;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #c7d1d6;
}

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section, layoutform {
display: block;
}

mark {
background-color: #a6dbed;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}

.float-left {
float: left;
}

.float-right {
float: right;
}

.clear-fix:after {
content: ".";
clear: both;
display: block;
height: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
color: #000;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
font-size: 1em;
}

h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

hr{
color: #009963;
background-color: #009963;
height: 20px;
}
/*------------------head area[logo]-------------------*/

.logo {
vertical-align:top;
height:97px;
width:216px;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.head{
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.div_line{
width: 990px;
height: 24px;   
}
.div_grey {
float: left;
height:24px;
width: 216px;
background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

.div_blue{
height:24px;
width: 761px;
background-color:#009963;
color:#ffffff;
float:  right;
//padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
.p div_blue{
font-size: 14px;
}
.empty{
height:10px;
}
.div_logo{
width: 990px;
height: 100px;   
}
.div_left_logo {
//vertical-align:top;
float: left;
height:100px;
width: 216px;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.div_bottom_logo{
margin-top: 268px; 
}
.div_right_logo{
height: 100px;
width: 761px;
float: right;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
/*-----------------navi_left area-----------------------*/
layoutform {
clear: both;
//background-color: #e2e2e2;
font-size: 1em;
height: 100%;
}
.div_navi{
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
width:216px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
}

/*------------------Contents area--------------------*/
.div_text{
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
vertical-align:top;
width:761px;
height: 100%;
//padding:0px 0px 0px 34px;
font-size:11px;
line-height:22px;
float: right;
}

.div_content {
vertical-align:top;
width: 990px;
height: 500px;
//border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
margin-left: 145px;
}
layoutbody .div_content{
padding: 30px;
}
/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 990px;
}

#body {
background-color: #efeeef;
clear: both;
padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.main-content {
    background: url("../Images/accent.png") no-repeat;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.featured + .main-content {
    background: url("../Images/heroAccent.png") no-repeat;
}

header .content-wrapper {
padding-top: 20px; 
}

footer {
clear: both;
//background-color: #e2e2e2;
font-size: 1em;
height: 100px;
}


/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
 .site-title {
color: #c8c8c8;
font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size: 2.3em;
margin: 0;
}

.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
background: none;
color: #c8c8c8;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
}


 /* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/
#login {
display: block;
font-size: .98em;
margin: 0 0 10px;
text-align: right;
}

#login a {
   // background-color: #d3dce0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#login a.username {
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#login ul {
    margin: 0;
}

#login li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}

.login_content{
margin-left: 50px; 
margin-top: 50px;
}
/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
font-size: 1.3em;
font-weight: 600;
margin: 0 0px 5px;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;

}

ul#menu li {
   // display: block;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

    ul#menu li a {
        background: none;
        color: #999;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul#menu li a:hover {
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

/*--------------------navi_left---------------------------*/
.tab_navi{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

.td_navi_left{
width:216px;
vertical-align:top;
font-size:11px;
line-height:21px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

* html .td_navi_left {
border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.navi_empty{
height:30px;
border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.symbol{
height:113px;
}

.tab_subnavi{
width:100%;
}
/* page elements
----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* featured */
.featured {
background-color: #fff;
}

.featured .content-wrapper {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    color: #3e5667;
    padding: 20px 40px 30px 40px;
}

    .featured hgroup.title h1, .featured hgroup.title h2 {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .featured p {
        font-size: 1.1em;
    }

 /* page titles */
 hgroup.title {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hgroup.title h1, hgroup.title h2 {
display: inline;
}

hgroup.title h2 {
font-weight: normal;
margin-left: 3px;
}

/* features */
section.feature {
width: 300px;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
}

/* ordered list */
ol.round {
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 0;
}

ol.round li {
    margin: 25px 0;
    padding-left: 45px;
}

    ol.round li.zero {
        background: url("../Images/orderedList0.png") no-repeat;
    }

    ol.round li.one {
        background: url("../Images/orderedList1.png") no-repeat;
    }

    ol.round li.two {
        background: url("../Images/orderedList2.png") no-repeat;
    }

    ol.round li.three {
        background: url("../Images/orderedList3.png") no-repeat;
    }

    ol.round li.four {
        background: url("../Images/orderedList4.png") no-repeat;
    }

    ol.round li.five {
        background: url("../Images/orderedList5.png") no-repeat;
    }

    ol.round li.six {
        background: url("../Images/orderedList6.png") no-repeat;
    }

    ol.round li.seven {
        background: url("../Images/orderedList7.png") no-repeat;
    }

    ol.round li.eight {
        background: url("../Images/orderedList8.png") no-repeat;
    }

    ol.round li.nine {
        background: url("../Images/orderedList9.png") no-repeat;
    }

 /* content */
 article {
float: left;
width: 70%;
}

 aside {
float: right;
width: 25%;
}

aside ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

    aside ul li {
        background: url("../Images/bullet.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
        padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
    }

 .label {
  font-weight: 700;
}

 /* login page */
  #loginForm {
//border-right: solid 2px #c8c8c8;
//float: left;
width: 100%;
 }

#loginForm .validation-error {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#loginForm .validation-summary-errors ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#loginForm .validation-summary-errors li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

#loginForm input {
    width: 250px;
}

#loginForm input[type="checkbox"],
#loginForm input[type="submit"],
#loginForm input[type="button"],
#loginForm button {
    width: auto;
}

 #socialLoginForm {
margin-left: 40px;
float: left;
width: 40%;
 }

#socialLoginForm h2 {
    margin-bottom:  5px;
}

#socialLoginList button {
margin-bottom: 12px;
 }

#logoutForm {
display: inline;
}

/* contact */
 .contact h3 {
font-size: 1.2em;
}

.contact p {
margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

 .contact iframe {
border: 1px solid #333;
margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
 }

/* forms */
fieldset {
border: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

fieldset legend {
    display: none;
}

fieldset ol {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

    fieldset ol li {
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

 label {
display: block;
font-size: 1.2em;
font-weight: 600;
 }

 label.checkbox {
display: inline;
 }

 input, textarea {
border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
background: #fff;
color: #333;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
padding: 5px;
width: 300px;
}

textarea {
font-family: inherit;
width: 500px;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
    border: 1px solid #7ac0da;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    background: transparent;
    border: inherit;
    width: auto;
}

input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"],
button {
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    border: 1px solid #787878;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: auto;
}

td input[type="submit"],
td input[type="button"],
td button {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

/* info and errors */
.message-info {
border: 1px solid;
clear: both;
padding: 10px 20px;
}

.message-error {
clear: both;
color: #e80c4d;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.message-success {
color: #7ac0da;
font-size: 1.3em;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.error {
color: #e80c4d;
}

/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
color: #e80c4d;
font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
display: none;
}

 input.input-validation-error {
border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

 input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
border: 0 none;
  }

.validation-summary-errors {
color: #e80c4d;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
display: none;
}


 /* tables
----------------------------------------------------------*/
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
margin-top: 0.75em;
border: 0 none;
}

th {
font-size: 1.2em;
text-align: left;
border: none 0px;
padding-left: 0;
}

th a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

th a:link, th a:visited, th a:active, th a:hover {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
}

th a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

th.asc a, th.desc a {
    margin-right: .75em;
}

th.asc a:after, th.desc a:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0em;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

th.asc a:after {
    content: '▲';
}

th.desc a:after {
    content: '▼';
}

td {
padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
border: 0 none;
}

tr.pager td {
padding: 0 0.25em 0 0;
}


/********************
 *   Mobile Styles   *
********************/
 @media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {

/* header
----------------------------------------------------------*/
header .float-left,
header .float-right {
    float: none;
}

/* logo */
header .site-title {
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* login */
#login {
    font-size: .85em;
    margin: 0 0 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

    #login ul {
        margin: 5px 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #login li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #login a {
        background: none;
        color: #999;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin: 2px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #login a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }

/* menu */
nav {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul#menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

    ul#menu li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }


/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.main-content,
.featured + .main-content {
    background-position: 10px 0;
}

.content-wrapper {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.featured .content-wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
}

/* page content */
article, aside {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}

/* ordered list */
ol.round {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    ol.round li {
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin: 25px 0;
    }

        ol.round li.zero,
        ol.round li.one,
        ol.round li.two,
        ol.round li.three,
        ol.round li.four,
        ol.round li.five,
        ol.round li.six,
        ol.round li.seven,
        ol.round li.eight,
        ol.round li.nine {
            background: none;
        }

 /* features */
 section.feature {
    float: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
 }

    section.feature img {
        color: #999;
        content: attr(alt);
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

/* forms */
input {
    width: 90%;
}

/* login page */
#loginForm {
    border-right: none;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
}

    #loginForm .validation-error {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

#socialLoginForm {
    margin-left: 0;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
}


/* footer
----------------------------------------------------------*/
footer .float-left,
footer .float-right {
    float: none;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

    footer p {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want help, you should post your code so we can replicate the issue.

Comment: I have added code, I can not upload snapshots as I am new and does not have enough reputution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. As I had divided header, body into different div sections, now I have made one main div for whole body and then sub div for sub sections. Works fine.